# How do I turn a local data frame in to a regular data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I used the below code:

```
library(dplyr)
by.tweet %>%
group_by(tweet) %>%
summarise(created = sum(created), number = sum(number)) 
data.frame()
```

and it prints:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
 tweet created number
 1 negative    <NA>  57876
 2  neutral    <NA> 124029
 3 positive    <NA>  92244
```

But I want this in a regular data frame. How could I write this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `as.data.frame` to convert to a data.frame i.e.

```
by.tweet %>% 
    group_by(tweet) %>%
    summarise(created = sum(created), number = sum(number)) %>%
    as.data.frame()
```